How to deploy nextjs standalone app into aws amplify
I have tried several ways available online and also tried aws docs with no luck
I am using nextjs 14 with monorepo and here is my amplify yaml file
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: apps/blog-mfe
    env:
      variables:
        AMPLIFY_MONOREPO_APP_ROOT: apps/blog-mfe
    frontend:
    # That zip file is generated by amplify. In local it would be .next folder generated
      buildPath: /
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm install -g pnpm
            - sh -c 'cd ../../.. && pnpm config set store-dir ./.pnpm-store'
            - pnpm install --prefer-offline --filter=blog-mfe
        build:
          commands:
            - pnpm install
            - pnpm run build
        postBuild:
          commands:
            - mkdir -p .next/standalone || sudo mkdir -p .next/standalone
            - mkdir -p .next/standalone/static || sudo mkdir -p .next/standalone/static
            - chmod -R 755 .next
            - cp -r apps/blog-mfe/.next/standalone/apps/blog-mfe/. .next/standalone
            - cp -r apps/blog-mfe/.next/static/. apps/blog-mfe/.next/standalone/static
            - echo 'require("apps/blog-mfe/.next/standalone/apps/blog-mfe/server.js")' > .next/standalone/server.js
      artifacts:
        files:
          - '**/*'
        discard-paths: yes
        baseDirectory: apps/blog-mfe/.next

App deployment successful but amplify site gives 404. Why? Did any one manage to deploy
